# Bind Visibility to a hashcode using IValueConverter

Tags: c#, wpf

```
public class HexToHandSelectedConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Int64 temp = UInt64.Parse(value, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        if (((Int64)temp & 0x0f) > 0) return Visibility.Collapsed;
        else return Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

im trying to bind Visibility to an int64 dependency property that contains a hexadecimal code that i am generating. the property will have a maximum value of 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF. a control should collapse once the last 4 digits (LAST HEX CHARACTER) has already been set by a function.

the code compiles but i am getting an InvalidCastException when running the program. 
Any thoughts or ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
I just realized that the converter was wrong. the dependency property that the control is binding to is actually a String that represents HEX numbers that gets converted to int64, modified and converted back to string whenever necessary.

now im having a problem with 
Int64 temp = UInt64.Parse(value, NumberStyles.HexNumber);

the code now wont compile. the string to hex conversion works outside this converter though..

Comment: On which line is the InvalidCastException occurring? It might help you to break that statement down a bit (i.e. from `if (((Int64)value & 0x0f) > 0)` to something like `var realValue = (Int64)value; var temp = realValue & 0x0f; if (temp > 0)`

Comment: Is `value.GetType() == typeof(Int64)`? You may want to check for nulls if your values are lazy loaded or just populated late.

Comment: the exception occurs on  if (((Int64)value & 0x0f) > 0)

Comment: I hope you've done the binding correctly, perhaps you could post the xaml for the same for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming value is always Int64. You may want to check for that.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
  long longValue;
  try {
    longValue = Convert.ToInt64(value);
  } catch {
    return Visibility.Visible;
  }

  if ((longValue & 0x0f) > 0) return Visibility.Collapsed;
  return Visibility.Visible;
}
```